# How to use sslEnabled config flag in aws-sdk v3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

In aws-sdk v2 there is an option to set `sslEnabled` flag.

Example

```
import { Kinesis } from "aws-sdk"; // v2

new Kinesis({
    endpoint: process.env.LOCALKINESISSTREAMENDPOINT,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    apiVersion: process.env.KINESIS_API_VERSION,
    sslEnabled: false, // required flag
})
```

I'm not able to find any similar option for aws-sdk v3.

Tried searching the documentaion, but no luck as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`Notable Changes` documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/preview/migrating/notable-changes/):

> **sslEnabled**
>
> v2: Whether SSL is enabled for requests.
>
> v3: *Renamed to tls*.